# Problem in saving .xlsm (excel) file using pandas dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, xlsm

I have two macro excel files(.xlsm file) with different information. I have written the python code that basically checks certain fields, and if that certain field is present then it saves in one folder, otherwise if that field is absent then it saves in another folder. I don't want any information removed from that excel file. I just wanted if that field is present then save the original file into that folder, otherwise save the original file in other folder. Code is not giving any error. But when I check the saved file, it is showing this error. Image Attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNYqk.png)

For testing, Input Files are attached [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WiPovnTOlxjHa9bw5WBhjYUHIqzFF7WO?usp=sharing)

```
from pathlib import Path
import time
import parser
import argparse
import pandas as pd
import os
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Process some integers.")

parser.add_argument("path", help="define the directory to folder/file")
parser.add_argument("--verbose", help="display processing information")

start = time.time()


def main(path_xlsm, verbose):
    if (".xlsm" in str(path_xlsm).lower()) and path_xlsm.is_file():
        xlsm_files = [Path(path_xlsm)]
    else:
        xlsm_files = list(Path(path_xlsm).glob("*.xlsm"))

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    
    for fn in xlsm_files:
        all_dfs = pd.read_excel(fn, sheet_name=None, header=None, engine="openpyxl")
        print(all_dfs)
        list_data = all_dfs.keys()
        all_dfs.pop("Lookups", None)
        all_dfs.pop("Instructions For Use", None)
        all_dfs.pop("Drop Down Boxes", None)
        all_dfs.pop("ResolutionLookups", None)
        
        for ws in list_data:  # Looping for excel sheet
            df1 = all_dfs[ws]
              
            if df1.iloc[3, 0] == "Client Representative" and df1.iloc[4, 1] == "DATE" and df1.iloc[4, 3] == "SHIFT":
                path_save = "C:\\Users\\ShantanuGupta\\Desktop\\Incoming\\Peel"
                df.to_excel(os.path.join(path_save, f"{fn.name}"), index=False)
            else:
                path_save = "C:\\Users\\ShantanuGupta\\Desktop\\Incoming\\Resolution"
                df.to_excel(os.path.join(path_save, f"{fn.name}"), index=False)
            
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    path = Path(args.path)
    verbose = args.verbose
    main(path, verbose)  # Calling Main Function
    print("Processed time:", time.time() - start)  # Total Time
```

**Can anyone help me to fixed this problem???**

Comment: Do you need to modify the files in any way?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using the `ExcelWriter` from pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('<filename>.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='<sheet_name>)

workbook  = writer.book
workbook.filename = '<filename>.xlsm'
writer.save()
```